# What are major resources to learn about Islam?

Tags: reading-quran

I was in a Muslim family, and as a result, I know lots of data and information about Islam. But I want to go deeper and understand more about Islam to decide whether I want to be a Muslim or not. I want some resources to understand fundamental concepts of Islam. I thought reading Quran is the first thing I've to do but some people told me that reading Quran without knowing the history of its emergence's time may give me a wrong concept of Islam. Because some orders in Quran were only perfect in that time.

So I want to know where can I find best resources to read about Islam and judge it? Is Quran enough? If I have to read history, what books are more suitable for my position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option could be reading Quran with a commentary (tafseer). A good commentary should explain the context in which a verse is revealed, as well as some discussions and different interpretations around it.

Comment: do you suggest a commentary?

Comment: I've read this a  while ago, and it seemed okay to me: https://www.amazon.com/Study-Quran-New-Translation-Commentary/dp/0061125873